# SAP Java Connector not working in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jco

I want to connect my Google App with SAP to retrive data from SAP.

I tried using [SAP Java Connector](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nwpi711/helpdata/en/48/70792c872c1b5ae10000000a42189c/content.htm) in simple Java application and it worked fine.

However it thorws an exception when I try to do the same thing in [Google App](https://cloud.google.com/java/).

Here is my code :

```
public static final void getConnection() {
    Properties connectProperties = new Properties();
    connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_ASHOST, SAP_IP);
    connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_SYSNR,  "00");
    connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_CLIENT, "350");
    connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_USER, SAP_USER_NAME);
    connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_PASSWD, SAP_PASSWORD);
    connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_LANG,   "en");

    try {
        JCoDestination destination = JCoDestinationManager.getDestination(SAP_DESTINATION);
        System.out.println("Attributes:");
        System.out.println(destination.getAttributes());
        System.out.println();
        destination.ping();
    } catch (JCoException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here SAP_DESTINATION, SAP_IP, SAP_USER_NAME and SAP_PASSWORD are the String variables having respective values.

Here is the exception thrown when I call this getConnection() method:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.RuntimeEnvironment.getRuntimeImplementation(RuntimeEnvironment.java:475)
at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.JCoRuntimeFactory.createRuntime(JCoRuntimeFactory.java:41)
at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.JCoRuntimeFactory.<clinit>(JCoRuntimeFactory.java:22)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
at com.sap.conn.jco.JCo.createJCo(JCo.java:52)
at com.sap.conn.jco.JCo.<clinit>(JCo.java:26)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:70)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:65)
at com.sap.conn.jco.JCoDestinationManager.getDestination(JCoDestinationManager.java:104)
at com.gulbrandsen.sap.SAPConn.getConnection(SAPConn.java:24)
at com.gulbrandsen.sap.GAESAPServlet.doGet(GAESAPServlet.java:9)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileUtils.serveWelcomeFileAsForward(StaticFileUtils.java:82)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet.maybeServeWelcomeFile(LocalResourceFileServlet.java:253)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet.doGet(LocalResourceFileServlet.java:120)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:128)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:512)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:429)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(DevAppServerFactory.java:454)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:315)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkParentAccess(ThreadGroup.java:135)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.<init>(ThreadGroup.java:117)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.<init>(ThreadGroup.java:96)
at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.JCoRuntime.<clinit>(JCoRuntime.java:125)
... 74 more
```

This same code works fine with simple java app.(Without Google SDK for Java)

Can any one confirm that the JCO jar is compatible with Google App or not.
Is this a issue with JCO or Google sdk ?

Or Can any one suggest me some other way to connect Google App with SAP.(instead of JCO)

Answer (score 0):

The SAP Java Connector offers a platform independent API for Java, but itself is platform dependent. It needs to load a platform dependent native library.
Please see SAP note [1077727](https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1077727) for a list of supported JREs and operating systems.

The SAP Java Connector uses the RFC protocol for communicating with SAP systems. As an alternative you may use HTTP/HTTPS instead. Please have a look at the Internet Communication Framework (ICF) and the Internet Communication Manager (ICM) for this. Maybe this link will be useful as an introduction:

https://help.sap.com/saphelp_qim100/helpdata/EN/48/641ea1bdbc51eee10000000a421937/frameset.htm